# How do you decouple getData with a private flag variable?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I have a custom UITableViewController class that is shared among a few ViewControllers of my app.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    ... 
    // Check if we are almost at the end of the scroll. If so, start fetching.
    // Doing this here is better than overriding scrollViewDidEndDragging
    if (indexPath.row >= [self.tableView numberOfRowsInSection:0] - 3) {
        [self refill];
    }

    return cell;
}
```

I would like to do pre-emptive fetching before the user has hit the bottom of the page.

However, I noticed that if the user scrolls up and then down again, my VC will trigger another fetching.

So I came up with a flag isFetching which checks to prevent double fetching. Unfortunately I am running asynchronous code and I need a way to reset this flag after my fetching operation has completed.

FeedVC:

```
- (void)refill {
    if (self.continueFetching && !self.isFetching) {
        NSLog(@"Fetching started");
        self.isFetching = true;
        AFJSONRequestOperation *operation = [self.delegate refill:^{
            NSLog(@"Fetching completed");
            self.isFetching = false;
        }];
        [self.pendingOperations addObject:operation];
    }
}
```

Delegate:

```
- (AFJSONRequestOperation *)refill:(void (^)(void))finishCallback {
    return [[ItemStore sharedInstance] fetchItemsForFeed:^(int itemsFetched, int nextOffset, bool hasNextPage) {
        finishCallback();
    } withFailureBlock:^{
        finishCallback();
    }];
}
```

I find it very painful to pass around a finish bloc in order to flip a boolean. does anyone have a better recommendation?

Comment: I think you should try implement your progressive refill on uitableview scrollview delegate methods like scrollviewdragended.

Comment: This logic could be set on the `completionBlock` of NSOperation: `operation = [[ItemStore sharedInstance] fetchItemsForFeed:NULL withFailureBlock:NULL];` and then `[operation setCompletionBlock:yourBlock];`

Comment: Also, instead of the flag, you could keep a reference to the fetch operation and just nullify it in the completion block. this way you can have the granularity to cancel the operation if needed.

Comment: @DanShelly care to elaborate on the reference to the fetch operation and nullifying it in the completion block part?

Comment: @iphonic yeah tried that before how would that change anything though

Answer (score 0):

Elaboration:

```
typedef void(^block_t)(void);
typedef void(^success_block_t)(int itemsFetched, int nextOffset, bool hasNextPage);
```

FeedCV:

```
/****************************************************************************/
/*!
 @note assume the declarations:
 @property (nonatomic,strong) NSOperation* fetchOp;
 @property (nonatomic,strong) NSOperationQueue* operationQueue;
 */
/****************************************************************************/
- (void) refill
{
    if (self.fetchOp) { //fetch is in progress
        return;
    }

    __block __weak id weakSelf = self;
    block_t completionBlock = ^{ //this will happen on a BG thread
        //Implement what ever logic seems to fit your FeedVC uppon completion
        //This will be called on the operation thread, so don't update UI here
        //Move to main thread UI updates
        [weakSelf setFetchOp:nil];
    };

    self.fetchOp = [self.delegate refill:completionBlock];
//                            successBlock:nil
//                               failBlock:nil];

    //If you can't change your delegate code then:
    //self.fetchOp = [self.delegate refill:nil];
    //[self.fetchOp setCompletionBlock:completionBlock];

    [self.operationQueue addOperation:self.fetchOp];
}
/****************************************************************************/
```

Delegate:

```
/****************************************************************************/
/*!
 @note If you can change this API add support for the blocks
 */
/****************************************************************************/
- (AFJSONRequestOperation*) refill:(block_t)completionBlock
//                      successBlock:(success_block_t)success
//                         failBlock:(block_t)fail
{
    AFJSONRequestOperation* op = [[ItemStore sharedInstance] fetchItemsForFeed:nil/*success*/
                                                              withFailureBlock:nil/*fail*/];
    [op setCompletionBlock:completionBlock];
    return op;
}
/****************************************************************************/
```

Comment: wait this won't solve my problem because self.fetchOp has to be implemented by its delegate. My problem right now is that i) I need to over-ride on fetchCompleted, ii) I don't want to expose any flags or variables to my delegates